# How to achieve CBR at low data rate in H.264?

Tags: algorithm, video, video-streaming, video-capture, codec

I am looking to find a solution to one of the many research works that has been already carried out in this field. I am looking into a problem which deals with finding a way to be able to set constant bit rates for h.264 codec which apparently does not support the same in some situations. Could you possibly provide me with some ideas ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to set constant bit rates with an existing library (like x264), or do you want to know the theoretical details of how a constant bitrate algorithm works?

Comment: The previous work was done with H 264 which according to the author was not able to maintain CBR. Therefore, all i want is an alternative which i could use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[this x264 diary entry (including the comments below)](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/249) may be of help. some sample commandline options are given in the comments. encoding cbr using x264 is not a usual thing, but it is helpful for streaming, so support was added. however, it is not clear what the lowest possible data rate is for a given input.